# network firmware version - what is means? and what the aspect of wrong firmware version

Tags: networking, network-interface, firmware

we have two physical machines that should be with the same HW  with `Rhel 7.5` version,

we checked the network card details by `ethtool -i`

**on the first we can see**

```
driver: i40e
version: 2.1.14-k
firmware-version: 7.10 0x800051a4 19.0.12
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:3b:00.1
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

on the second we can see

```
driver: i40e
version: 2.1.14-k
firmware-version: 5.40 0x80002d36 18.0.17          <------------------------------
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:05:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
```

what is strange , is that both network card have - `version: 2.1.14-k`
**but the firmware-version  is different**

***is it possible?***

***second*** - dose wrong firmware-version , can be the cause of network failure??

Comment: 2.1.14-k is the version of the driver, -k indicates that it’s the kernel-provided driver. The firmware version depends on the card or motherboard.

Comment: so its not really a problem ? , or do we need to be worry about this ?

Comment: Your first question isn’t a problem. I imagine firmware versions change things, and presumably fix bugs, so I wouldn’t go so far as saying that different (not “wrong”) firmware versions won’t cause network problems. You’ll have to ask Intel...

Comment: ok , I see , so is it possible to upgrade the firmware version on physical dell machines ?

Comment: I have no idea...

Comment: Is this an Intel X710/XXV710/XL710 adapter? [Dell 19.5.0 Firmware for X710, XXV710, and XL710 adapters](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=yp4r0), [Update Utility for Intel® Ethernet Network Adapter 700 Series](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24769/Non-Volatile-Memory-NVM-Update-Utility-for-Intel-Ethernet-Network-Adapter-700-Series?product=82947)

Comment: do you means by - Update Utility for Intel® Ethernet Network Adapter 700 Series  - we can upgrade the firmware ?

Comment: If this is an adapter you have and if it's Dell branded, I'd try the Dell Update. Check  "Compatible Systems" and "Applies to" on the bottom of the page first.